# Recursive pagination of Instagram feed. How can I do this faster?

Tags: objective-c, pagination, instagram, nsurlsession, instagram-api

I'm working with Instagram API and want to show a screen with user's photos ordered by number of likes.
So, I need to get an array with all photos.

There is how I do this:

```
- (void)fetchAllPostsFromURL:(NSURL *)url success:(void(^)(NSArray *posts))success {

    __block NSArray *allPosts = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

        if (!error) {

            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];
            if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] && !jsonError) {

                NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
                for (NSDictionary *jsonPost in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                    DVVPost *post = [[DVVPost alloc] initWithJSONData:jsonPost];
                    [tempArray addObject:post];
                }
                allPosts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
            }

            NSURL *paginationURL = [self getPaginationURLFromResult:result];

            if (paginationURL) {

                [self fetchAllPostsFromURL:paginationURL success:^(NSArray *posts) {
                    allPosts = [allPosts arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:posts];
                    success(allPosts);
                }];

            } else {

                success(allPosts);
            }

        } else {

            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

It works, but it takes pretty much amount of time. As I see, there is 2-3 requests per second, each gives me 20 photos.

How can I make that faster?

API: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Make the requests ```asynchronous``` so they run and update in the background.

Comment: @Dan how can I do that? Now, to run the next request, I need to have a response from the current one with pagination URL. I can add photos to screen part by part, but I need to sort them and I don't sure, that it will look better, than just loading indicator.